# How to subscribe to an Observable in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to subscribe to an Observable so I can display it in HTML with Angular, doing `console.log(player)` works fine however I get

```
Type 'Player' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Player>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.ts(2740)
```

I've tried using `.pipe()`,

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="(player$ | async) as player">
  <div *ngIf="player.characterUid">
    {{player.characterName}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Component:

```
player$: Observable<Player>;
subPlayer: Subscription;

selectPlayer(matEvent: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    this.inputFriends = matEvent.option.value;
    this.selectedPlayer = matEvent.option.value;
    this.inputP = false;

    this.subPlayer = this.playerProvider.get$(matEvent.option.value.userUid).subscribe(
      (player: Player) => {
        this.player$ = player; // Type 'Player' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Player>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.ts(2740)
      }
    );
  }
```

Provider:

```
get$(uid: string): Observable<Player> {
    return this._getDoc(uid)
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(
        map((sPlayer: ServerPlayer) => sPlayer ? new Player(sPlayer) : null)
      );
  }

  private _getDoc(uid: string): AngularFirestoreDocument {
    return this.afs.doc(`players/${uid}`);
  }
```

I'm just trying to assign `player$` so I can display it in the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `player$` is not an observable, it's already the result of the observable.

```js
player: Player; // <-- here
subPlayer: Subscription;

selectPlayer(matEvent: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    this.inputFriends = matEvent.option.value;
    this.selectedPlayer = matEvent.option.value;
    this.inputP = false;

    this.subPlayer = this.playerProvider.get$(matEvent.option.value.userUid).subscribe(
      (player: Player) => {
        this.player = player; // <-- here
      }
    );
  }
```

```html
<div *ngIf="player"> <!-- here -->
  <div *ngIf="player.characterUid">
    {{player.characterName}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in case we don't need to use async pipe you answer correct ,well done

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to subscribe , async pipe will subscribe and get the value for you ‍♂️

```
player$: Observable<Player>;

selectPlayer(matEvent: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    this.inputFriends = matEvent.option.value;
    this.selectedPlayer = matEvent.option.value;
    this.inputP = false;

    this.player$= this.playerProvider.get$(matEvent.option.value.userUid);

  }
```

> The async pipe takes care of subscribing and unwrapping the data as
>   well as unsubscribing when the component is destroyed, so you don't need **subPlayer**

*template*

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(player$ | async) as player">
  <div *ngIf="player.characterUid">
    {{player.characterName}}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

[Async Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm just trying to assign player$ so I can display it in the HTML

`this.player$ = this.playerProvider.get$(matEvent.option.value.userUid);`

this method returns an observable, so if you want to assign `player$`, you can do it that way. In your html template, you're using `| async` which handles subscribe/unsubscribe automagically.

Comment: the async pipe approuter is more cleaner and handling the subscribe is great thing 